# Cron expression that runs for every 2 years

Tags: cron

I need to run a particular script starting from Jan 1st of 2019 at 12 AM and next it should run on Jan 1st 2021 at 12 AM, then on Jan 1st 2023 at 12 AM and soon.

Comment: Ah, you're already mentioning cron. So you're at least a little bit familiar with it? What exactly stops you from writing an expression for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cron expression to schedule a job every two years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745514/cron-expression-to-schedule-a-job-every-two-years)

Answer (score 5):

You can create and/or check the cron expression format with http://www.cronmaker.com/

```
0 0 0 1 1 ? 2019/2
```

This should work. It will run the task on

```
1.  Tuesday,   January 1, 2019 12:00 AM
2.  Friday,    January 1, 2021 12:00 AM
3.  Sunday,    January 1, 2023 12:00 AM
4.  Wednesday, January 1, 2025 12:00 AM
5.  Friday,    January 1, 2027 12:00 AM
```